# Combine dataframes only by mutual rownames

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to combine about **20** dataframes, with different lengths of rows and columns, only by the mutual rownames. Any rows that are not shared for ALL dataframes are deleted. So for example on two dataframes:

```
     Patient1   Patient64   Patient472
ABC     28          38          0
XYZ     92          11          998
WWE      1          10          282
ICQ      0          76          56
SQL     22          1002        778
```

combine with

```
     Pat_9   Pat_1   Pat_111
ABC    65      44       874
CBA    3       311      998
WWE    2       1110     282
vVv    2       760      56
GHG    12      1200     778
```

The result would be

```
   Patient1 Patient64 Patient472  Pat_9  Pat_1  Pat_111
ABC    28      38        0         65     44      874
WWE    1       10       282         2     1110    282
```

I know how to use `rbind` and `cbind` but not for the purpose of joining according to shared rownames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
merge(d1, d2, by = "row.names")
  Row.names Patient1 Patient64 Patient472 Pat_9 Pat_1 Pat_111
1       ABC       28        38          0    65    44     874
2       WWE        1        10        282     2  1110     282
```

for more than two you can use a tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
lst(d1, d2, d2) %>%
  map(rownames_to_column) %>% 
  reduce(inner_join, by="rowname")
```

Comment: Does it work for many dataframes, cause it is giving me error: `'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical`

Comment: Then you didn't read my question. I did say I have about 20 dataframes and gave an *example* of two dataframes. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Ahh sorry my fault. See my edits

Answer (score 2):

Try this considering change `list` arguments to `df1 , df2 , df3 , ... , df20` your data.frames

```
l <- lapply(list(df1 , df2 ) , \(x) {x[["id"]] <- rownames(x) ; x})

Reduce(\(x,y) merge(x,y , by = "id") , l)
```

Comment: What does this error mean? `Error in x[["id"]] <- rownames(x) : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace`

Answer (score 1):

You can first turn your `rownames_to_column` and use a `inner_join` and at last convert `column_to_rownames` back like this:

```r
df1 <- read.table(text="     Patient1   Patient64   Patient472
ABC     28          38          0
XYZ     92          11          998
WWE      1          10          282
ICQ      0          76          56
SQL     22          1002        778", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "     Pat_9   Pat_1   Pat_111
ABC    65      44       874
CBA    3       311      998
WWE    2       1110     282
vVv    2       760      56
GHG    12      1200     778", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr) 
library(tibble)
df1 %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>% rownames_to_column(), by = "rowname") %>%
  column_to_rownames()
#>     Patient1 Patient64 Patient472 Pat_9 Pat_1 Pat_111
#> ABC       28        38          0    65    44     874
#> WWE        1        10        282     2  1110     282
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Option with list of dataframes:

```r
dfs_list <- list(df1, df2)
transform(Reduce(merge, lapply(dfs_list, function(x) data.frame(x, rn = row.names(x)))), row.names=rn, rn=NULL)
#>     Patient1 Patient64 Patient472 Pat_9 Pat_1 Pat_111
#> ABC       28        38          0    65    44     874
#> WWE        1        10        282     2  1110     282
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: And in my case with 20 df, I should `inner_join` each new df to the already joined dataframes?

Comment: Hi @ProgrammingNoob, I added an option when you have a list of dataframes.

Comment: Thanks @Quinten ! However the option of many dataframes returns an empy dataframe :(